# The tests in tests Explorer are invisible

Tags: c#, .net, coded-ui-tests, test-explorer

I am using .Net 4.5, Coded UI framework and CUITE extension to creating tests.
When I am creating PageObjects, I should inherit it from CUITE_BrowserWindow class. Then the Tests in TextExplorer become unavaliable. 
     Here is example of my PageObject Class:

```
public class MainSearchPage:CUITe_BrowserWindow
{
    public MainSearchPage(string title) : base(title) { }
    private CUITe_HtmlEdit searchField
    {
        get
        {
            CUITe_HtmlEdit field = new CUITe_HtmlEdit("Name=q");
            return field;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is example of my  Coded UI test Class:

```
[CodedUITest]
public class GoogleSearchTest
{
    public GoogleSearchTest()
    {
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GoogleSearhTesting()
    {
        Browser.CreateBrowser("https://www.google.com");
        PageManager.SearchPage.Search("s");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly the issue you're having, but for me the tests started showing up when I launched Visual Studio as an Administrator.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but not help(